# Windows Phone 7 Pivot and Scroll Viewer Event handling

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building a gallery on WP7.0.

I have a pivot element, each pivot item contains an ScrollViewer witch contains a Image.
I use the pivot element for the page switching and the ScrollViewer for the picture translation animation.

I want to do the following:

When the the Flick event occurs and the image is zoomed, I want the pivot NOT to change to the next item but rather so sent the event to the ScrollViewer and execute his translation code.

I trying to do this by setting the IsHitTestVisible and IsEnabled attributes for the Pivot but of course, as you guest, it doesn't work.

Any other ideas will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="pivot"  
                    Width="480"
                    Height="768" 
                    Background="Red" 
                    IsEnabled="True" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Image>
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener >

                        </toolkit:GestureListener>
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </Image>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Cna you provide a mock up? or some other way of indicating what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but may be you should handle PivotItem manipulation events,
and run your transform in event handler ?